# G++ ABI compatibility list

Tags: c++, linux, unix, g++, abi

I have compiled my preload file on Ubuntu server (two files for x32 and x64). Where I can get list, in which I will see with what OS my compiled files are compatible and with what I should recompile for compatibility?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Linux App Checker](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/linux-application-checker-getting-started) developed by ISPRAS and The Linux Foundation. It's designed to perform cross-distro compatibility checks for Linux applications. See sample reports [here](http://ispras.linuxbase.org/index.php/Linux_App_Checker_Getting_Started#Using_Web-UI).

[image]

Comment: That looks quite powerful and a lot more fluid than running multiple VMs.

Comment: Thank you! What about unix os like FeeBSD, does this checker can check it also?

Comment: Linux binary compatibility is not turned on by default in FreeBSD. You need a lot of additional software for that. See [Chapter 11 Linux Binary Compatibility](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/linuxemu.html) in FreeBSD Handbook. So, the checker doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by attempting to execute the program on various Linux distributions in a virtual machine. Pick the top three most popular Linux distributions or the ones your users are most likely to have.

Also, you may be better off to distribute a statically linked binary and offer the source code to others who wish to build it themselves (if you are allowed to distribute source).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand you, but, if my understanding is not that wrong, I'd start by `ldd -v`. Any OS that is architecture compatible *and* has the dependent libraries installed in compatible versions should work.

Next, if you plan to support more architectures, you need explicitly to know it and cross compile for every one of it.

So, you must recompile for:
 1. Every different architecture.
 2. When library versions are not compatible.

This last one is more tricky, since your code may need specific versions to work, but you must know it anyway from start.

Please tell me if it is not what you wanted.

Comment: I just want to check if my linux compiled ld_preload will work on, for example, Solaris. My compile command is g++ -fPIC -m32  -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -ldl -o test.so test.cpp

Comment: I don't think Solaris binary loader will load Linux compiled ELFs with no complain even if it targets the same architecture. I have no way to test it, but would be very glad if you could do it with a simple full statically linked test. My guess is that you will always need to recompile when you change the OS (Solaris, BSD, etc.)